# Question about polynomials: factor $4x^2 + 25$ into a product of linear terms

Tags: polynomials

So we are asked to factor $4x^2 + 25$ into linear terms (over $\mathbb{C}$ - it's not specified in the problem because the instructions are sloppy, anyways)

so I know that the answer is (2x+5i)(2x-5i)

but why is it that when you solve for x using ordinary algebra:

> Set the polynomial equal to 0
>
> $4x^2 + 25 = 0$
>
> $x = \pm 5i/2$

but $(2x+5i)(2x-5i) ≠ (x+\frac{5i}{2})(x-\frac{5i}{2})$

I'm not sure how to recover the 4

[I looked at this other question from stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170071/can-any-polynomial-be-factored-into-the-product-of-linear-expressions)

Comment: We can look at the leading coefficient.

Comment: Roots of $(x-a)(x-b)$ and that of $K(x-a)(x-b)$ ($K \neq 0$) are the same but they are not the same polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$4x^2+25$ is not monic. That is, it doesn't have leading coefficient $1$. If a polynomial $p$ has roots $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$, it doesn't necessarily follow that $p(x)=(x-\alpha_1)\cdots(x-\alpha_n)$.

For example $2x-4$ has the solution $x=2$, but clearly $2x-4 \neq x-2$. In general, what we can say is the following: if $p(\alpha)=0$, then $(x-\alpha)$ is a factor of $p(x)$.

Another way to think about this is: $p(x)$ and $\lambda p(x)$ have the same roots for any $\lambda \neq 0$. So clearly just finding the roots cannot recover the polynomial uniquely, only up to a constant factor.

Comment: oh yea that's right I don't know why I overlooked that it's not monic